# Intent is always null when taking picture

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to take a picture and put the image in an ImageView.  When the code reaches onActivityResult the Intent is always null.  The code seems to be right as far as I have researched but I can't get it to work.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode== RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap bmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        switchImage(bmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: post the stack trace.

Comment: are you setting the result using setResult()?

Comment: Do you have android.permission.CAMERA in manifest?

Comment: @marcin_j If he did not have the permission, he would not even have been able to open the camera to start with.

Comment: have you pass any extra parameter with intent.

Comment: @Pierre he is not saying he is able to 'open the camera'

Comment: @marcin_j `When the code reaches onActivityResult the Intent is always null.`. Is it possible to get to ActivityResult if the camera/intent is not started, or not able to be started?

Comment: @Pierre I made a small project with OP code to test is, and I get non null "data" even with no permissions. I have no idea whats wrong with this code.

Comment: @rex8tom What else do you have which we do not know about? Do you have a `Provider` something like that in your solution? Please upload your solution somewhere so we can check it, the code you mentioned above is not the issue here.

Comment: @marcin_j I had a similar problem with Samsung devices that had custom roms installed and I solved it by using the below answer. I'm guessing rex8tom has a issue that is related to what I had.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to take a picture. This works on Samsung devices that have custom roms loaded as well:

On capture button clicked:

```
private void cameraCapture() {
        File photoFile = null;
        if (pic_number >= 5) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Maximum amount of pictures taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File not created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Intent camIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                camera_picture_uri = photoFile.toString();
                camIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(camIntent, pic_number);
                pic_number++;
            }
        }
    }


private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null);
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
        return image;

    }
```

In onActivityResult:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        setCameraPicture(data);
    }

private void setCameraPicture(Intent data) {
        // TODO
        // Auto-generated method stub
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(camera_picture_uri);
            ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(camera_picture_uri);
            int rotation = 0;
            int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
                rotation = 90;
                bm = rotateCameraImage(rotation, file);
            } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
                rotation = 180;
                bm = rotateCameraImage(rotation, file);
            } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
                rotation = 270;
                bm = rotateCameraImage(rotation, file);
            } else {
                bm = rotateCameraImage(rotation, file);
            }

            // Set bitmap to imageview

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


private Bitmap rotateCameraImage(int rotation, File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotation);

        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        int scale = 8;
        o.inSampleSize = scale;
        o.inPurgeable = true;
        o.inInputShareable = true;

        Bitmap sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.toString(), o);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        System.gc();
        return bitmap;
    }
```

**EDIT**

The ExIfInterface is used to check what rotation the image needs to be set to to display correctly

Comment: I had your null intent problem and this fixed it.